# How do I reverse approval of an edit?

Tags: discussion

I reviewed a post, and then clicked "approve edit", when I actually meant to reject the edit. How can this be reversed?

Comment: It can't be. But it doesn't matter. Everyone makes reviewing mistakes on occasion.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go edit the post yourself to revert it.

Comment: OK. Tried to do that, but the edit was rejected by someone else and does not show up in the answer. I just want to remove the evidence that I was so boneheaded as to approve that edit in the first place.

Comment: @brasshat Maybe if you include the link in your question here, someone kind can do it for you then.